# Should I be linking to controller actions like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a user, whose table in the database contains a boolean column for admin status. I want an admin to be able to change the admin status of any other user. The relevant view is:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    ...
    <% if current_user && (current_user.id == user.id || current_user.admin) %>
      ...
      <% if current_user.admin %> 
        <td><%= link_to 'Make admin', user.id.to_s + '/make_admin', {:method => 'post', :action => 'make_admin'} %></td>
        <% if user.admin %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Revoke admin', user.id.to_s + '/revoke_admin', {:method => 'post',  :action => 'revoke_admin'} %></td>
        <% end %>
      ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I wasn't sure how else to do it so I cobbled together the URL by concatenating the user's ID and the specific query. My controller begins with the restrictions which seem to prevent unauthorized access to these methods:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  before_action :admin_logged_in, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :make_admin, :revoke_admin]
```

And finally, my routing file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...

  post ':id/make_admin' => 'users#make_admin'
  post ':id/revoke_admin' => 'users#revoke_admin'
```

It seems to work, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it. I've read the routing guide on Rails but little of it makes sense to me right now. I've tried linking directly to the user with

```
<%= link_to 'Make admin', user, {:controller => 'users', :action => 'make_admin'} %>
```

But I would receive an error about no route being defined for [POST]/user_id or something along those lines. That feels like the better solution in this case; if it is, what should I do in the routes.rb file to address this?

Comment: Just as an aside - you shouldn't solve this with string concatenation, you should use a named route like in the answers below.  But, if you were using string concatenation, instead of doing this `user.id.to_s + '/revoke_admin'`, do this: `"#{user.id}/revoke_admin"`.  This **interpolation** is much safer, more readable and is generally the preferred way of dynamically generating a string.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Do you have an example why it is safer?

Comment: `nil + "foo" => NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`.  `123 + "foo" => TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum`.  `"#{nil}foo" => "foo"`.  `"#{123}foo" => "123foo"`

Comment: Basically this is the same as calling `to_s` on everything in the list of elements being added together, except that you don't need to remember to call `to_s` every time.  Even if you have added `to_s` to everything to make it safe, you have an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a helper to your routes like this :

```
post ':id/make_admin' => 'users#make_admin', as: 'make_admin'
```

Now `make_admin_path(user.id)` will link to that. You can view all helpers either by running `rake routes` in your site's directory or going to `localhost:3000/rails/info`

As for the error you got, I can't say for certain without seeing the full error, but when you `<%= link_to 'text', user %>` ruby interprets `user` at the path, and tries to find a `user_path` and the `{:controller => 'users', :action => 'make_admin'}` is a hash of HTML attributes that get added.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your routes as follows:

```
resources :users do 
   member do 
     post 'make_admin', as: :make_admin
     post 'revoke_admin', as: :revoke_admin
   end
end
```

I hope this helps you out